# After upgrading to chrome 94, I cannot request https resources from the http website. What should I do?

Tags: google-chrome

After upgrading to chrome 94, I cannot request https resources from http website

For example, `https://api.b.com` cannot be accessed in `http://a.com`

The API of `https://localhost:345` is not accessible even in `http://localhost:123`

Is there a way to turn off this limitation of chrome?

Answer (score 1):

set

```
chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests
```

disabled

Comment: thank you.. it work... It's very cumbersome.